# Force a page to be re-downloaded, rather than fetched from browser cache - Apache Server

Tags: apache, caching, browser-cache

Ive made a minor text change to our website, the change is minor in that its a couple of words, but the meaning is quite significant.

I want all users (both new and returning) to the site to see the new text rather than any cached versions, is there a way i can force a user (new or returning) to re download the page, rather than fetch it from their browser cache ?

The site is a static html site hosted on a LAMP server.

Answer (score 0):

This depends totally on how your webserver has caching set up but, in short, if it's already cached then you cannot force a download again until the cache expires. So you'll need to look at your cache headers in your browsers developer tools to see how long it's been set for.

Caching gives **huge** performance benefits and, in my opinion, really should be used. However that does mean you've a difficulty in forcing a refresh as you've discovered.

In case you're interested in how to handle this in the future, there are various cache busting methods, all of which basically involve changing the URL to fool the browser into thinking its a different resource and forcing the download.

For example you can add a version number to a resource so you ask for so instead of requesting index.html the browser asks for index2.html, but that could mean renaming the file and all references to it each time.

You can also set up rewrites in Apache using regular expressions so that index[0-9]*.html actually loads index.html so you don't need multiple copies of the file but can refer to it as index2.html or index3.html or even index5274.html and Apache will always serve the contents of index.html.

These methods, though a little complicated to maintain unless you have an automated build process, work very well for resources that users don't see. For example css style sheets or JavaScript.

Cache busting techniques work less well for HTML pages themselves for a number of reasons: 1) they create unfriendly urls, 2) they cannot be used for default files where the file name itself is not specified (e.g. the home page) and 3) without changing the source page, your browser can't pick up the new URLs. For this reason some sites turn off caching for the HTML pages, so they are always reloaded.

Personally I think not caching HTML pages is a lost opportunity. For example visitors often visit a site's home page, and then try a few pages, going back to the home page in between. If you have no caching then the pages will be reloaded each time despite the fact it's likely not to have changed in between. So I prefer to have a short expiry and just live with the fact I can't force a refresh during that time.